# Equal Length Center Aligned List Items in Horizontal Nav Bar

Tags: html, css

I am looking to create a nav bar that stretches 100% and has equal lengths for each list item. The code I have right now does stretch 100% but some of the items are not center aligned and the "home" and "contact" items have unwanted white space. What is the best solution for this problem?

Also if you have time, I would like to border out the dropdown menu without doubling the borders. If you look at my code you can see that it has an outside border and also a left border on the individual list item (besides the first item). Help on this problem would also be appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/IL1agD5.png"/></a></div>
        <div class="chapter"><a><img src="http://i.imgur.com/RPIvgdD.png"/></a></div>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>

            <li><a href="#">About ▾</a>
                <ul class = "sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">History</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Brothers</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="#">Philanthropy ▾</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Kovacs Color Run</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Greek God</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Boys & Girls Club</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            <li><a href="#">Membership</a>
            <li><a href="#">Photos</a>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

        </ul>
    </nav>
```

**CSS**

```
    #wrapper {
    min-width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

header {
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    background:black;
    margin:0 auto;

}
.logo{
    padding-left:10px;
    float:left;
    padding-top:5px;
}

.chapter {
    float:right;
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-right:10px;
}


.menu{
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}

ul.menu {
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #ACB5B5 0%, #E2F0EA 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #ACB5B5 0%, #E2F0EA 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #ACB5B5 0%, #E2F0EA 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #ACB5B5 0%, #E2F0EA 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ACB5B5 0%, #E2F0EA 100%);
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    border-left:solid 1px #22674A;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align:center;
}

ul.menu > li {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
    width:16.66%;
    border-style:1px #22674A;
}
ul.menu li:first-child a {
    border-left:none;
}
ul.menu li:last-child a {
    border-right:none;
}
ul.menu ul {
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E2F0EA 0%, #ACB5B5 100% );
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding:0 auto;
    border-left:none;
    border:solid 1px #22674A;
}
ul.menu a {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    color: #22674A;
    line-height: 40px;
    width:140px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:500;
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
    border-left:solid 1px #22674A; 
}
ul.menu li {
    list-style: none;
}
ul.menu li:hover {

}
ul.menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0;
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/rsheo0Lv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCyrillus does it the right way.

You also have to remove the width from the links:

```
ul.menu a {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    color: #22674A;
    line-height: 40px;
    /* width: 140px;   remove !!*/
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
    border-left: solid 1px #22674A;
}
```

To remove the border in your dropdown add the following:

```
ul.menu ul a{
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stefan_wave/rsheo0Lv/5/)

Answer (score 1):

you need to clear `nav` or `ul` from previous `float`ting elements :

```
.menu{
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0 ;/* just fine with 0 */
    text-align:center;
    clear:both; /* clear from floats ahead in the flow */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rsheo0Lv/1/